# Lua base converter

Tags: lua

I need a base converter function for Lua. I need to convert from base 10 to base 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11...36 how can i to this?

Comment: It does seem a little odd that bases 2 through 36 are available in the text to number direction, but not the other way.

Comment: i am counting ones :) Thue Morse-Sequence

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the `string` to `number` direction, the function [`tonumber()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-tonumber) takes an optional second argument that specifies the base to use, which may range from 2 to 36 with the obvious meaning for digits in bases greater than 10.

In the number to string direction, this can be done slightly more efficiently than [Nikolaus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554315/lua-base-converter/3554437#3554437) by something like this:

```
local floor,insert = math.floor, table.insert
function basen(n,b)
    n = floor(n)
    if not b or b == 10 then return tostring(n) end
    local digits = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    local t = {}
    local sign = ""
    if n < 0 then
        sign = "-"
    n = -n
    end
    repeat
        local d = (n % b) + 1
        n = floor(n / b)
        insert(t, 1, digits:sub(d,d))
    until n == 0
    return sign .. table.concat(t,"")
end
```

This creates fewer garbage strings to collect by using `table.concat()` instead of repeated calls to the string concatenation operator `..`. Although it makes little practical difference for strings this small, this idiom should be learned because otherwise building a buffer in a loop with the concatenation operator will actually tend to O(n<sup>2</sup>) performance while `table.concat()` has been designed to do substantially better.

There is an unanswered question as to whether it is more efficient to push the digits on a stack in the table `t` with calls to `table.insert(t,1,digit)`, or to append them to the end with `t[#t+1]=digit`, followed by a call to `string.reverse()` to put the digits in the right order. I'll leave the benchmarking to the student. Note that although the code I pasted here does run and appears to get correct answers, there may other opportunities to tune it further.

For example, the common case of base 10 is culled off and handled with the built in `tostring()` function. But similar culls can be done for bases 8 and 16 which have conversion specifiers for `string.format()` (`"%o"` and `"%x"`, respectively).

Also, neither Nikolaus's solution nor mine handle non-integers particularly well. I emphasize that here by forcing the value `n` to an integer with `math.floor()` at the beginning.

Correctly converting a general floating point value to any base (even base 10) is fraught with subtleties, which I leave as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: `tostring` differs from the (encouraged) `string.format` on large numbers, see https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-tostring

Answer (score 3):

you can use a loop to convert an integer into a string containting the required base. for bases below 10 use the following code, if you need a base larger than that you need to add a line that mapps the result of x % base to a character (usign an array for example)

```
x = 1234
r = ""
base = 8

while x > 0 do
    r = "" ..  (x % base ) .. r
    x = math.floor(x / base)
end
print( r );
```

Comment: Caution: this doesn't handle negative values or non-integral values. Negative is easy to address, you just need to discover the sign and make it positive before the loop. Non-integers are much harder.