# Reversing an decode function

Tags: lua

I'm trying to reverse a decode function. This function takes a string and a key and encodes the string with that key. This is the code:

```
function decode(key, code)
  return (code:gsub("..", function(h)
    return string.char((tonumber(h, 16) + 256 - 13 - key + 255999744) % 256)
  end))
end
```

If I input `7A` as `code` and `9990` as `key`, it returns `g`

I tried reversing the operators and fed back the output of the decode function but I get an error becauase `tonumber()` returns nil. How can I reverse this function?

Answer (score 2):

By using the answer to this [Lua base coverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554315/lua-base-converter) and flipping the operators of the decode function, I was able to convert back the input.

This is the whole code:

```
function encodes(key, code)
  return (code:gsub("..", function(h)
    return string.char((tonumber(h, 16) + 256 - 13 - key + 255999744) % 256)
  end))
end

local floor,insert = math.floor, table.insert
function basen(n,b)
    n = floor(n)
    if not b or b == 10 then return tostring(n) end
    local digits = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    local t = {}
    local sign = ""
    if n < 0 then
        sign = "-"
    n = -n
    end
    repeat
        local d = (n % b) + 1
        n = floor(n / b)
        insert(t, 1, digits:sub(d,d))
    until n == 0
    return sign .. table.concat(t,"")
end

function decodes(key, code)
  return (code:gsub(".", function(h)
    out = (string.byte(h) - 256 + 13 + key - 255999744) % 256
    return basen(out,16)
  end))
end

a = encodes(9999, "7c7A")
print(a) --prints: `^
print("----------")
b = decodes(9999, a)
print(b) --prints: 7C7A
```

Comment: More compact form: `return (code:gsub(".", function(c) return ("%02X"):format((c:byte()+13+key)%256) end))`